# Multiset Combination

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

How many Combinations can you make with the set **{1,1,2,3,4}** taken 2 at a time? If I do this in the way I do in Permutation: C(5,2) / 2!, I end up in wrong answer.

Actually, there are 7 Combinations: 1 1, 1 2, 1 3, 1 4, 2 3, 2 4, 3 4.

How should I solve this one.

Thank You!

Can I here use the ${k+n-1\choose r}$ formula?

Comment: You just did! If you want a more general solution to the number of different selections you can make of two items from a collection in which all the numbers $1,\dots,n$ appear at least once and $m$ appear more than once, then the answer is ${n\choose 2}+m$.

Comment: Sorry, C(5,2)/2! gives me 5 but the answer is 7

Comment: I meant that 7 is the correct answer. $\frac{1}{2}{5\choose 2}$ is the wrong way of dealing with the two 1s. The correct approach is in my previous comment.

Comment: OK, how did you come to the that: C(n,2)+m. Why C(n,2)

Comment: Either the pair is of the form $k,k$ or it is not. There are $m$ possible pairs $k,k$ and ${n\choose 2}$ possible pairs $h,k$ with $h\ne k$.

Comment: Can You please write it little expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalising slightly, you want the number of different selections you can make of two items for a collection in which all the numbers $1,\dots,n$ appear at least once, and $m$ of these numbers appear more than once (whilst no other numbers outside $1,\dots,n$ appear at all). For example, you might be selecting from $\{1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6\}$.

If the selection is of the form $k,k$, then there are just $m$ possible values for $k$, so $m$ different possible selections. If the selection is of the form $h,k$ with $h\ne k$, then $h,k$ are chosen from $1,2,\dots n$, so the usual ${n\choose 2}$ works fine. Or starting from scratch, we can pick $h$ in $n$ ways, then $k$ in $n-1$ ways, but that gives us every selection twice so there are $n(n-1)/2$ different selections.

Putting that together, there are a total of $m+{n\choose 2}$ different possible selections.

In the particular case given in the question, $\{1,1,2,3,4\}$ we have $n=4,m=1$, so there are ${4\choose 2}+1=6+1=7$ different possible pairs. In the case $\{1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6\}$ you have $n=6,m=3$, so the answer is ${6\choose 2}+3=18$.

Comment: Why cant we use : C(k+r-1, r)

Comment: well can we us the same technique for all type of problems